# How to read Open Graph and meta tags from a webpage with a url

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta

I want my website to be able to pull up information about a web page when the user pastes a link into the post box, similar to Facebook.

I was wondering how sites like Google, Reddit and Facebook are able to retrieve thumbnails, titles and descriptions with just a URL.

Anyone know how they do this?

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithm is rather simple: fetch the page, analyze content, extract text&images&title&whatever, build preview.
However there are a lot of difficulties for particular use cases. Menus, banners and adds, text structure - plenty of different details that require very scrupulous processing. AFAIK there is no algorithm that can solve this task in 100% cases (yes, Google's and other algorighms aren't perfect).

About Reddit. Since it's opensourced, you can find how they do it exactly.
Here is the code you're looking for: 
https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/scraper.py

Yandex has API that allows to do the same. You can find more [here](http://api.yandex.com/rca/) and [here](http://api.yandex.com/rca/doc/dg/).

Comment: Thanks! I should have updated this post, but I assumed it had died. I got what I was looking for with cURL. I load the webpage in PHP and just scan for meta tags. I only use images if there is an open graph or a twitter card available, but since not every site uses these I've been thinking about scanning deeper. Didn't think about ads though. Thanks for the resources!

Comment: The most interesting part starts when there is no markup at all :)